# Create a loop on UIScrollView

Tags: xcode, loops, uiscrollview, swift3

I can scroll back and forth on the views but I can't loop the views so it scrolls back when I'm on ViewController3 and forward on ViewController1 to create a loop. How would I do this?

The code below is what I've done so far.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let vc0 = ViewController0(nibName: "ViewController0", bundle: nil)

    var frame0 = vc0.view.frame
    frame0.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
    vc0.view.frame = frame0

    self.addChildViewController(vc0)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc0.view)
    vc0.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    let vc1 = ViewController1(nibName: "ViewController1", bundle: nil)

    var frame1 = vc1.view.frame
    frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
    vc1.view.frame = frame1

    self.addChildViewController(vc1)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc1.view)
    vc1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    let vc2 = ViewController2(nibName: "ViewController2", bundle: nil)

    var frame2 = vc2.view.frame
    frame2.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 2
    vc2.view.frame = frame2

    self.addChildViewController(vc2)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc2.view)
    vc2.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    let vc3 = ViewController3(nibName: "ViewController3", bundle: nil)

    var frame3 = vc3.view.frame
    frame3.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 3
    vc1.view.frame = frame3

    self.addChildViewController(vc3)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc3.view)
    vc3.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: Double(self.view.frame.size.width * 4), height: Double(self.view.frame.size.height - 66))

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I'd suggest you drop the use of UIScrollView altogether and use UIPageViewController instead. It makes this sort of thing trivial because you only have to supply one page at a time, and doing infinite or looping scrolling of the kind you describe is easy because you just keep supplying the "next" view controller in the looping series each time you are asked for it. Plus it handles the whole parent-child dance for you (not that there's anything wrong with how you're doing it).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Could you please give me more detail about how to use the UIPageViewController instead?

Comment: Here's a downloadable example project: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p311pageController/ch19p626pageController/AppDelegate.swift In your case, instead of returning `nil` after the third VC, you would just return the first VC and presto, you're looping.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused, the example project you showed me is for the AppDelegate.swift but I've been working from the ViewController.swift. Do I just copy that code and paste it into my ViewController or AppDelegate?

Comment: Well, you should never copy code and paste it. I'm showing how the concept works. You should use the code to help you _understand_ page view controllers and then write your _own_ code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I'm sure I'll figure it out.